# Ray Tracing In Mathematical Spaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, knot-theory, geodesic, connections

I really enjoyed the [Not Knot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcLfb0PhfO0) video, but I don't fully understand the mathematics which is going on there.

They are animating the space of the complement of the Borromean rings, but you can't just animate a topological space.  What is the least amount of structure needed so that you can do ray tracing?  I guess you need geodesics and angles, so a Riemann manifold should suffice.  But can one do also with an affine connection?  You would have geodesics I think, but I don't know about angles, which you would need to map points of the viewport to geodesics.

And if so, what exactly is the process of turning this subset of $\mathbf{R}^3$ (the complement of the Borromean rings) into an affine connection?  Can you define this for any open subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a bit careful with stating the question since you can do raytracing in the complement of a knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$ just fine in a trivial way (it's $\mathbb{R}^3$, so use the euclidean metric). The point here is that the complement of the borromean rings happen to have a complete constant-curvature hyperbolic structure, and the video is showing what it looks like from within this space with this structure.

The video shows how you can construct this hyperbolic structure using a dodecahedron inside hyperbolic space. For 3-manifolds with hyperbolic structures, you can also triangulate them with tetrahedra and solve certain equations that guarantee you have a hyperbolic structure, by virtue of each tetrahedron being a tetrahedron in hyperbolic space, which are glued together in a way that give a hyperbolic structure for the 3-manifold. With such tetrahedra, you can do raytracing by doing raytracing with a hyperbolic metric inside these tetrahedra, and then whenever you hit the face of a tetrahedron you continue from the other tetrahedron glued along this face. This is how I understand [SnapPy's inside view](https://im.icerm.brown.edu/portfolio/snappy-views/) to work.

Another way to understand this is that hyperbolic 3-manifolds are quotients of hyperbolic space by a discrete subgroup of the isometry group, so you can do raytracing by lifting to the universal cover (hyperbolic 3-space). The triangulation is in some sense a way to represent such an isometry group, but you can work with the group directly.

For other spaces, you can hope that the space has one of the [eight model geometries for the geometrization conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture) and use similar techniques. People like Henry Segerman have been working on doing raytracing (or at least accurate renderings) for each of the model geometries. For non-prime spaces or spaces with non-trivial JSJ decompositions, then my understanding is that there's not a unique way to raytrace in the complement of a knot.